# how to get the last entry in the system object array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I use the following command to generate a log file in `C:\tmp` with this naming convention `computername_yearmmddhhmm.txt`

```
/xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_${env:COMPUTERNAME}_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').txt"
```

to read the output of this file using PowerShell I use the code attached below , to obtain the last 20 lines of the logfile I use the below code

```
$Fireeyefilename = Get-Item  $filename*.txt

Write-Output ("FireEye Connection Status");
Write-Host "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
$foreeyeconnection = Get-Content $Fireeyefilename[$Fireeyefilename.count – 1] -Tail 20 | select-string "m=TCPConnect";
Write-Output ("$($Fireeyefilename[$Fireeyefilename.count – 1])");
Write-Output ("$foreeyeconnection");
```

as shown above, I save part of the file name in the variable `$filename`, then I store all the log files created with the naming convention `xagt_hostname_*` in the variable `$Fireeyefilename`, and then I read the content of this file using `Get-Content`.

The problem is that some time the variable (`$Fireeyefilename`) contains a single log file
like that

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> $Fireeyefilename


    Directory: C:\tmp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                    
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                    
-a----       13/07/2023     10:58        8416798 xagt_computername_20230713_105844.txt                                                                                       



PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> $Fireeyefilename.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

and the `$Fireeyefilename` variable type becomes `System.IO.FileSystemInfo`

and some time the `$Fireeyefilename` variable has multiple log logfiles and the variable  type becomes a system array like:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> $Fireeyefilename.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                                                                  



PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> $Fireeyefilename


    Directory: C:\tmp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                    
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                    
-a----       13/07/2023     10:58        8416798 xagt_computername_20230713_105844.txt                                                                                       
-a----       13/07/2023     11:03        8428108 xagt_computername_20230713_110307.txt                                                                                       
-a----       13/07/2023     11:03        8428108 xagt_computername_20230713_110337.txt
```

I need to read the last log file I generated ,in other words thefile with the recent "LastWriteTime"
so I use this code:

```
Get-Content $Fireeyefilename[$Fireeyefilename.count – 1] -Tail 20 | select-string "m=TCPConnect";
```

as I mentioned previously, when  the variable `$Fireeyefilename` has a single file name
and its  type is `system.IO.FileSystemInfo`, it will hvave no `Count` property but the code works
and when the variable `$Fireeyefilename` type is `System.Array`, I got the last file using

```
Get-Content $Fireeyefilename[$Fireeyefilename.count – 1] -Tail 20 | select-string "m=TCPConnect";
```

Sometimes I couldn't get the last log file I generated  using this code:

```
Get-Content $Fireeyefilename[$Fireeyefilename.count – 1]
```

so is there a mmethod to get the last log file with the LastWriteTime in he system array variable Last `$Fireeyefilename`

Take into consideration that I should to generate this file in the `C:\tmp` location
why there logfiles with the same name, because a lot of users have to generate this file in the same location and is there a suggestion to enhance the code, kindly let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `@(...)` array subexpression operator to force PowerShell to treat single-item output as an array:

```
# use @() to ensure `$FireEyeLogFiles` contains an array, 
# regardless of whether there's 0, 1, or multiple files
$FireEyeLogFiles = @(Get-Item $filename*.txt)

# index `-1` will give you the last item in the array
$latestFireEyeLogFile = $FireEyeLogFiles[-1] 
if (-not $latestFireEyeLogFile) {
  Write-Warning "No log files found!"
}
else {
  $latestFireEyeLogFile |Get-Content -Tail 20 |Select-String -Pattern 'm=TCPConnect'
}
```

Comment: tanks Mathias
really appreciate you support I will try and let you know